# Is there a faster way to generate .csv files as an alternative to groupby and looping?

Tags: python, pandas

I have to generate dozens of .csv files with millions of rows and dozens of columns. I am currently generating files by doing a `groupby` of columns A and B and looping to dynamically generate files with `to_csv`. Below is an example of what I am trying to do. Is there a faster technique? My actual dataframe takes more than 10 minutes to run and is becoming quite painful, and this is something that would be beneficial on several projects.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 3, size=(10000,3)), columns=list('ABC'))
%timeit for (a,b), x in df.groupby(['A', 'B']): x.to_csv(f'{a}_Invoice_{b}.csv', index=False)
```

Time elapsed:

```
45.2 ms ± 1.58 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Also, I created a function, which had a similar time, but I wanted to post it, so people could more easily modify it for for using `%timeit` if the answer is more than one line of code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def generate_invoices(df):
    for (a,b), x in df.groupby(['A', 'B']):
        x.to_csv(f'{a}_Invoice_{b}.csv', index=False)
    return

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 3, size=(10000,3)), columns=list('ABC'))
%timeit generate_invoices(df)
```

Comment: I think here main bottleneck is write to huge amount of files.

Comment: Thanks for your input @jezrael . These all have to go to individual customers, so it is a requirement.

Comment: btw, if use `for (a,b), x in df.groupby(['A', 'B'], sort=False):` it is better performance with real data?

Comment: I'll have to test on the other computer when I have in front of me next week. I'll try that and let you know if it helped.

Comment: Tested with sample and it is slowier :(

Comment: just out of curiosity, why r u creating this individual files? and for semantics is it any different if you say ```for a,b in df.groupby(['A','B']): b.to_csv bla bla``` ?

Comment: From the real dataset, Column A is the Customer (e.g. Company A, Company B, Company C) and Column B are the different multiple offices of each customer (e.g. London, New York, San Francisco). Each customer needs a different .csv for each of their offices. Semantics of the code don't matter to me as long as the right data gets outputted faster.

Comment: If I am doing it in a way that is already optimal, then that is okay with me. I was just wondering if I was doing something that was very sub-optimal. If I save 10% or 20% of time, then it doesn't really matter. I was wondering if there was something fundamentally faster that could increase the performance 10x or 100x.

Comment: I suspect there might be a way to this quickly with awk, though it's beyond my skill level. Since you aren't doing any aggregation in the `groupby`, it would be sufficient to just sort by `A` and `B`, then split into new files whenever either value changes, right? Maybe try the resident Unix boffins on here.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander for this particular project, I am not doing any aggregations, but for others I am. Thanks, that is helpful. If it's easy for you, then please post what your suggestion would be as an answer. Otherwise, I'll have a play with it myself.

Comment: If you're aggregating, you can do it in Pandas and export to csv, then you're able to do the split in any language. I don't have any ideas but I posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61171088/split-csv-file-thousands-of-times-based-on-groupby).

Comment: @DavidErickson I think Alex's awk answer on that question will be close to what you want - just need to add headers afterwards. Any way you could time it on your data and let me know if it works/is faster?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander I've added in another example that does a second pass, adding the header in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split csv file thousands of times based on groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61171088/split-csv-file-thousands-of-times-based-on-groupby)

Comment: @Alex yeah, looks perfect. Waiting on OP for feedback